# Bootstrap 4: Stop collapse from pushing content down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Collapse and it's working perfectly, I just want to have one thing changed, if possible. Is there a way to stop it from pushing down the content beneath it, but instead to go over it? Is that possible to achieve? And how?

Here's the basic HTML for it:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
<div>Content goes here</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code should work!

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

#collapseExample {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">Content goes here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Felix!

Comment: FYI, with that z-index set to only 1, if there is a form inside of the modal pop-up, as with my application, none of the buttons will work. I removed the z-index and it didn't hurt anything, plus my form was able to submit once again. This is what I used (margin-top was used because the modal was too high on my page): `.content {
    position: relative !important;
}
#newUserModal {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:75px;
}`

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `.align-items-end` class to your menu container.
this class used flex property introduce in BS4.